# Unable to refresh datatable in jsf after tab change

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsf, datatable

This is my requirement. I am supposed to add a record and upon successful addition and clicking on the 'View' tab, the datatable should refresh, but the table remains unchanged. I am fetching the data into the datatable from a backing bean using the getter method.

Inside datatable:

```
<p:dataTable id="ci_table" value="#{ciConfigBean.ciList}" var="cid" scrollable="true" selectionMode="single" selection="#{ciConfigBean.ciConfigSave}"
            rowKey="#{cid.ciConfigId}" editable="true" resizableColumns="true">
```

I even tried using javascript methods by calling them from onTabChange event.

1st function:

```
function onLoad() {
             alert("tab"); 
            var oTable;
            oTable = $('#ci_table').dataTable();
            oTable.fnClearTable( 0 );
            oTable.fnDraw();
        }
```

2nd function:

```
var oTable;
            $(document).ready(function() {
                    oTable = $('#ci_table').dataTable({
                        "bProcessing" : true,
                        "bServerSide" : true,
                        "sAjaxSource" : '${request.contextPath}'
                                + '/ciConfigBean/getCiList'
                        });
                        oTable.fnReloadAjax();
                });
```

Tab change code:

```
<p:tab id="ci" title="CI">
            <p:tabView id="insideCi" onTabChange="onLoad()"
                activeIndex="#{home.activeInner}">
                <p:tab id="ciList" title="CI List">
                    <ui:include src="ci/ciList.xhtml" />
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab id="newCi" title="New CI">
                    <ui:include src="ci/newCi.xhtml" />
                </p:tab>
            </p:tabView>
        </p:tab>
```

But nothing seems to work. Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, guess there is no proper way to do so... So as a workaround, I added a commandbutton to refresh manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding dynamic="true" on the tabview tag. That should do the trick, assuming your save method is working, which I can't see from your post. No JavaScript is needed.

Comment: I tried using the 'dynamic' attribute. But still no result. I am adding a new record in the New CI tab, and its saved successfully. After this, if I click on the View tab, the list is not refreshed.

Comment: I have tried using dynamic="true",but it is not working. whenever I create a new values in the new CI tab, it is saving successfully in the database. but when I select the CI >List, the datatable is not filled with new values.

Comment: Can you query the actual database and see if the record is actually there? If so, does the datatable update when you refresh the whole page? Are you using a lazy datatable? Again, it will be much easier to help you if you post your bean code.

Comment: I have checked the database, it is saving succesfully, but the newly added value is not reflecting in the datatable. The datatable is updated with new values only if I reload the whole page again, until that there is no change in the datatable.

Comment: Are you not using a lazy data model? If not, you have to manually reload the list you feed to the dataTable component.

Comment: No I am not using lazy data model

Comment: I am not understanding why do I need to add the lazy attribute here. Please explain. I actually need to refresh the datatable once the tab is changed. This is not happening. There is no call going to the bean when the tab is changed from New Ci to View CI list.

Comment: You don't need it. I just use it always because it doesn't load all the records at once; this is particularly useful if you have a large table. Since you're not using it, you're probably using a list to pass data to the dataTable, correct? In that case, you need to refresh that list after you save the record. Again, the code for the whole bean would have been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

@Andre, the datatable will update when I refresh the whole page. But it does not update when I change the tab. Here is the Save method in my bean:

```
public void saveCiConfig() throws SystemException {
    long ciId = CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment(CIConfig.class
                    .getName());
            ciConfigSave.setCiConfigId(ciId);
            ciConfigSave.setProjectId(0);
            ciConfigSave.setParentCIConfigId(0);
            ciConfigSave.setCreatedDate(new Date());
            ciConfigSave.setCreatedBy(FacesUtil.getUserId());
            ciConfigSave.setUpdatedDate(null);
            ciConfigSave.setUpdatedBy(0);
            if (enable == Boolean.TRUE) {
                ciConfigSave.setStatus(DataConstant.STATUS_ACTIVE);
            } else {
                ciConfigSave.setStatus(DataConstant.STATUS_INACTIVE);
            }
            ciConfigSave.setSetupComplete(Boolean.FALSE);
            try {
                  CIConfigLocalServiceUtil.addCIConfig(ciConfigSave);
                FacesMessageUtil
                        .addGlobalInfoMessage("ci.message.submitSuccess");
                new Home().setActiveOuter(0);
                new Home().setActiveInner(1);
                setEditMode(Boolean.FALSE);
                resetInit();
            } catch (SystemException e) {
                FacesMessageUtil
                        .addGlobalErrorMessage("ci.message.submitFailed");
                log.error("error while saving the CI Configuration", e);
            }
```